# Phonegap build error app not showing correct information

Tags: phonegap-build

I made my first app using the online phonegap build, when I installed the app it loads my website not the app, what cause this error? I'm new to mobile apps. Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: *Mobile app* are not *web apps*. You should not be loading websites in your app. If you are doing this, you do not understand mobile apps. -- You should to start over. What do you want to do?

Comment: I created this app using html, javascript and css, after building it the pages I made don't show, the website shows, I thought maybe the problem was the reverse web I link I put, eg com.site.app for site I put the website, still looking and trying to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay, start over with working boilerplates. You might want to read the last one first. Then test with the first one.

- [An HTML Boilerplate for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html)
- [Three (3) Phonegap Build Boilerplates for For Android and iOS](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-19.codesnippets.html)
- [Hybrid HTML5 Boilerplates: Breaking the Chains of Legacy](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-20.jssnippets.html) - A roundup of boilerplates for Hybrid Mobile Application Development